# cgridveiw to display fetched data via customized query

Tags: yii-extensions, yii, yii-components

I am a newbei in yii, when a person clicks on a category display him all products under that particular category in a gridview

view
productcategory

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'admin-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->SelectedCategoryProducts,
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'Name',
    'Model',
    'Brand',
    'Price',

    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
 )); ?>
```

controller
product

```
    public function actionProductcategory($id)
```

{

```
$model= Product::model()->SelectedCategoryProducts($id);
    var_dump($model);


    $this->render('productcategory',array(
        'model'=>$model,'id'=>$id,
    ));
```

}
  model
   product

```
  public function SelectedCategoryProducts($id)
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Product', array(
 'criteria'=>array(
                        'select'=>'name,model,price,brand',
        'condition'=>'category=:category',
                        'params'=>array(':category'=>$id),
    )));
    var_dump($dataProvider);
   return $dataProvider;
   }
CException

Property "CActiveDataProvider.sellerSelectedCategoryProducts" is not defined.
```

PLEASE HELP! I am losing my mind on this ... not able to display in gridview.

Comment: I guess, 'dataProvider'=>$model->SelectedCategoryProducts, In this line SelectedCategoryProducts is function and need id as parameter. You have to be use like :  'dataProvider'=>$model->SelectedCategoryProducts($id)

Comment: :) yes, your application is throwing error for this line ; 'dataProvider'=>$model->sellerSelectedCategoryProducts,

Comment: i did try that PHP notice

Undefined variable: id .....

Comment: you have to call the function like `$model->SelectedCategoryProducts()` in cgridview

Comment: what  should be done to to get it displayed in gridview any idea?

Comment: @tisha you have to pass id. like 1 in your function which is category id in your case

Comment: @kumar_v   PHP warning

Missing argument 1 for Product::sellerSelectedCategoryProducts(), called in D:\wamp\www\testfolder\protected\views\seller\productcategory.php on line 9 and defined

Comment: ya i am passing category id itself but doesnt wrk :(  @naveengoyal

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help
**Controller file**

```
public function actionProductcategory($id)
      { 
$model=new Product;
$this->render('productcategory',array('model'=>$model,
'id'=>$id));
 }
```

**In View file**

```
'dataProvider'=>$model->SelectedCategoryProducts($id),
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
'columns'=>array(
    'name',
    'model',
    'brand',
    'price',
```

change them to lowercase which are your original column names

Comment: Property "Product.Name" is not defined.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: change the attributes name in your SelectedCategoryProducts() too. change them to lowercase

Comment: i did try that Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Pass $id to your view file.

```
$this->render('productcategory',array('model'=>$model,'id'=>$id));
```

Then pass id to model function in ccgridview function.

```
'dataProvider'=>$model->SelectedCategoryProducts($id),
```

Comment: Property "Product.Name" is not defined.

Comment: `Product.name`. not 'Name'. In your table, you have `name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Product', array(
     'criteria'=>array(
                            'select'=>'name,model,price,brand',
            'condition'=>'category=:category',
                            'params'=>array(':category'=>$id),
        )));
```

this can retrieve needed data....  first check that data is perfect ... is it right after that take second step....

Comment: CException

Property "CActiveDataProvider.sellerSelectedCategoryProducts" is not defined.

Comment: but the data is perfect

Comment: sellerSelectedCategoryProducts is product model function ...?

Comment: basics if you are calling model function it can be called like this $model->functionName()  or if it is field of model it can be called like the way u call it...  $model->fieldname ...  like   $model->name if name is a field of data table ....  if it is method or function it should be like $model->save() or $model->validate() ... () at the end of method or function name...

Comment: SelectedCategoryProducts  is function in product model

Comment: what is the last error you are getting.... update the question accoording to new errors you are getting...

Comment: $model->SelectedCategoryProducts($id = ? )  at  'dataProvider'=>$model->SelectedCategoryProducts,  like

Comment: 'dataProvider'=>$model->SelectedCategoryProducts($id = "value" ),